# HTML / CSS Submenu

Tags: html, css

I have been trying quite a few guides on getting sub-menus to work. Some which include JS. Now I'm trying a just css approach but I'm kinda stuck on getting the submenu to work for me.

My code is on fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PLb5K/

To do a basic test I have done

```
#nav ul li ul {
 display: none; }

#nav ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute; }
```

UPDATE

```
    #nav ul:hover .sub {
     display: block;
     position:absolute;
     }
```

fixes the "not working on hover" issue but any list item will show the sub menu. Please could anyone help on how to make it so only the single parent will show the submenu.

Comment: For example purposes, you should remove the PHP from the HTML, and use the rendered HTML.

Comment: anyway I can keep the php? the navigation is an included file. To stick to the rule of 'Duplication Is Evil'

Comment: Subnav doesn't show on hover

Comment: ok what do you want your menu to look like? dropdown? submenus on the right?...

Comment: do you need an horizontal or vertical menu? your fiddle needs a cleanup, you're using a #nav that isn't there. The UL needs to be "inside" the <li></li> tag, after the <a></a>. The result looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PLb5K/9/ is this correct?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PLb5K/11/ ?

Comment: Your JSfiddle link doesnt include your "basic test" that you include in your question. could you update your fiddle code thanks

Comment: Your fiddle cannot include php...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a basic html/css example for you:

### the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PLb5K/14/)

## css

```
ul  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 100px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li {
    background-color:grey;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; 
    padding:4px 8px;
    margin:0;
    zoom: 1; 

}
ul li a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul li ul.sub{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:4px;
    margin-left:-8px;
}
ul li:hover ul.sub{
    display:block;
}
```